# Excel: 2-way linkages for cells on both source sheet and destination sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

first time listener, first time caller.  I'm a forester trying to create a business plan template using Excel for other similar trades-people.  Want to create a table with 2-way linkages that shows up on each worksheet.

The problem:
I want to make it easy to see and manipulate several basic assumptions/variables as I go from sheet to sheet (Acres, Yield, etc).  Rather than toggle between worksheets or shared views, I want these assumptions to show up on each sheet in a workbook/document.  I want to be able to manipulate them on *ANY of the sheets, not just the source sheet.

These would be 2-way linkages (that is, not just referencing a named cell from the source sheet). The cells would link from a source sheet to all the destination sheets. Each cell can be manipulated on any sheet, not just the source sheet.

On the page it might look like this: the same small table in the same place on each sheet.  Or it might be the first two columns on each sheet.

Is this possible?  Does this require a VBA solution.

(I know how to name cells and link between sheets - not the problem.  I also know how to view multiple windows at a time - not the solution I want.)

Apologies for any breaches of etiquette.

Comment: Pretty sure 2-way linkage would require VBA, if you want to enter the data in same box that shows it. You could do it by using a `Worksheet_Change` sub in each sheet. 
 Although a bit hard to say exactly how without concrete examples.

Comment: Thank you - is this a kind of Macro?To give an example: I have a small table, two columns, left column is the parameter (Acres, Yield per Acre, Price per Gallon, etc) and the right column is a quantity.  The user determines the quantity as an assumption for the business plan.  This small table would show up on each page.

Answer (score 1):

So this is an example of how you theoretically could set it up using Macro.

I have a table in the range `A1:D5` including headers, which I have copied to the exact same location on three sheets.
Then I add the following code to each sheet, by right-clicking the sheet tab and selecting "show code".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A2:D5")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets(1).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Sheets(2).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Sheets(3).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot on how it looks:

[image]

So the `Worksheet_Change` checks for any change made in the sheet.
First I tell it to only look at changes made inside the table `Range("A2:D5")`, in the example omitting the header.
Then I set the value of that same cell on every sheet to the new value.
Obviously setting the value on the original sheet is redundant, but this is just for easily being able to copy and run the exact same code on all sheets.

Lastly the `Application.EnableEvents = False` prevents any changes made by the macro to trigger the `Worksheet_Change` subroutine. As this would end up in an infinite loop.

Table in action: 
[image]

**EDIT**

If you have many sheets, change the amount of sheets, or just like flexible code that doesn't repeat itself, you should just loop through the sheets.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A2:D5")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice tutorial material *(+1)*

Comment: Thank you again - I will try this.