# Excel 2 way linkage in different sheets and different range

Tags: microsoft-excel, links, visual-basic

I'm trying to link 2 range of cells in a 2 way link. Meaning, if you change a value in a cell it changing the value on other cell and vice-versa.

For reference:

[Excel: 2-way linkages for cells on both source sheet and destination sheets](https://superuser.com/questions/1406612/excel-2-way-linkages-for-cells-on-both-source-sheet-and-destination-sheets/1714922#1714922)

The solution there is working like a charm when the ranges are the same on both sheets, but, on my workbook, i can not use the same range.

On the example, it's using range a2:D5 for all the sheets but i'd like to get it to work from a2:D5 on the first sheet to H3:K6 on the second one.

I've tried many variant but my knowledge of visual basic is pretty limited and even after a few hours, i can't find any solution.

Thank you, really :-)

Comment: Did you try to change the Range in VBA code from A2:D5 to H3:K6?

Answer (score 0):

### First, Some Disclaimers

- This is my **first time** writing Excel Visual Basic code.
- This code is almost certainly un-optimized and likely to have edge cases where things break; correct replication and synchronization code is **tough to write**.
- This code **definitely** could be more modular; it'd benefit from a pub-sub model for wiring linked tables together. Right now, the code is copy-pasted with special care given to modify which tables are targeted in which file (see the diff).
- There is **almost certainly** a better way to do what you're wanting to do.
- ⚠️ **Please don't rely on this code for production use. Consider it an academic exercise.** ⚠️

### A Demo and the Example File

[image: Demoing the feature]

File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e23izdjd1vm83pw/superuser-1406612-two-way-sync-across-sheets.xlsm?dl=0

### And Now, the Code

For syncing from `Table1` in `Sheet1` to `Table2` in `Sheet2`:

```vbs
Public PriorCount As Long
Public PriorRows As Long
Public PriorColumns As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    PriorCount = Application.Range("Table1").ListObject.Range.Cells.Count
    PriorRows = Application.Range("Table1").ListObject.ListRows.Count
    PriorColumns = Application.Range("Table1").ListObject.ListColumns.Count
End Sub

'
' When I wrote this code, only God and I understood it.
'
' Now, only God knows.
'
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'
' TODO: Handle column/row deletions that alter where the Table's absolute position is (low priority)
'
' if something goes wrong, let the user know
' and give up, being sure to re-activate events
On Error GoTo OhNo

' get references to both table objects
Dim table1 As ListObject
Set table1 = Application.Range("Table1").ListObject
Dim table2 As ListObject
Set table2 = Application.Range("Table2").ListObject

' get current count of cells and rows/cols
Dim CurrentCount As Long
Let CurrentCount = table1.Range.Cells.Count
Dim CurrentRows As Long
Let CurrentRows = table1.ListRows.Count
Dim CurrentColumns As Long
Let CurrentColumns = table1.ListColumns.Count

' if our current row or column counts differ from prior,
' *and* there is no intersection between the target and
' table, then it means that we've removed rows or columns
' on the edge.
If Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), table1.Range) Is Nothing _
    And ((CurrentRows <> PriorRows) Or (CurrentColumns <> PriorColumns)) Then

    ' Debug.Print "Edge removal"

    ' Turn off events to avoid infinite loop
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' calculate the offset between Table1 and Table2
    table1Row = table1.Range.Row
    table1Col = table1.Range.Column
    table2Row = table2.Range.Row
    table2Col = table2.Range.Column
    
    ' these directions must be switched between
    ' Sheet1 and Sheet2. the row and col offset
    ' tell us which direction to move to apply
    ' the change in the other sheet. here, we go
    ' from Table1 to Table2, so we subtract 1 from 2
    rowOffset = table2Row - table1Row
    colOffset = table2Col - table1Col

    ' this is actually a pretty straightforward thing to sync.
    ' get the edge of the rows or cols, and delete everything
    ' past that in the other table.

    ' removing rows
    If CurrentRows < PriorRows Then
    
        RowsToRemove = PriorRows - CurrentRows
        RemoveWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
        
        table2.DataBodyRange.Offset(RemoveWhereTable2 - table2Row - 1, 0) _
            .Resize(RowsToRemove, table2.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count) _
            .Rows.Delete
    
    End If
    
    ' removing columns
    If CurrentColumns < PriorColumns Then
    
        ColsToRemove = PriorColumns - CurrentColumns
        RemoveWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
        
        table2.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, RemoveWhereTable2 - table2Col) _
            .Resize(table2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, ColsToRemove) _
            .Columns.Delete
    
    End If
    
    ' turn events back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

' if the change occurred anywhere inside Table1, then sync it to
' Table2 as well
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), table1.Range) Is Nothing Then

    ' calculate the offset between Table1 and Table2
    table1Row = table1.Range.Row
    table1Col = table1.Range.Column
    table2Row = table2.Range.Row
    table2Col = table2.Range.Column
    
    ' these directions must be switched between
    ' Sheet1 and Sheet2. the row and col offset
    ' tell us which direction to move to apply
    ' the change in the other sheet. here, we go
    ' from Table1 to Table2, so we subtract 1 from 2
    rowOffset = table2Row - table1Row
    colOffset = table2Col - table1Col

    ' we're adding rows or columns
    If CurrentCount > PriorCount Then
    
        ' Debug.Print "Added"
        ' The only way for a target to be non-empty
        ' and for CurrentCount > PriorCount is for
        ' the user to be adding an entry to the
        ' bottom of the list or the right. let's
        ' check for that.
        
        ' let's assume target is totally empty
        targetEmpty = True
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            ' for adding rows, everything is empty.
            ' but for columns, the first row isn't empty.
            ' it's a default column header string.
            If cell.Value <> Empty And Not cell.Value Like "Column*" Then
                targetEmpty = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        
        ' if not... go to Escape. We're adding to the bottom or right.
        If targetEmpty = False Then GoTo Escape
        
        ' otherwise... handle injecting rows or columns.
        ' Disable events to perform updates on table2.
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        ' figure out what we're adding and where
        
        ' adding rows
        If CurrentRows > PriorRows Then
        
            ' for adding/removing rows/cols, they've
            ' already been added to Table1. Just need
            ' to update Table2
            RowsToAdd = CurrentRows - PriorRows
            AddWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
            
            For i = 1 To RowsToAdd
                table2.ListRows.Add (AddWhereTable2 - table2Row + i - 1)
            Next
        
        ' adding columns
        ElseIf CurrentColumns > PriorColumns Then
        
            ' for adding/removing rows/cols, they've
            ' already been added to Table1. Just need
            ' to update Table2
            ColsToAdd = CurrentColumns - PriorColumns
            AddWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
            
            For i = 1 To ColsToAdd
                table2.ListColumns.Add (AddWhereTable2 - table2Col + i)
            Next
        
        End If
        
        ' update globals
        PriorCount = CurrentCount
        PriorRows = CurrentRows
        PriorColumns = CurrentColumns
        
        ' turn events back on
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    ' we're removing rows or columns
    ElseIf CurrentCount < PriorCount Then
        Debug.Print "Deleted"
        
        ' turn off events to apply updates
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        ' removing rows
        If CurrentRows < PriorRows Then
        
            ' for adding/removing rows/cols, they've
            ' already been added to Table1. Just need
            ' to update Table2
            RowsToRemove = PriorRows - CurrentRows
            RemoveWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
            
            table2.DataBodyRange.Offset(RemoveWhereTable2 - table2Row - 1, 0) _
                .Resize(RowsToRemove, table2.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count) _
                .Rows.Delete
        
        ' removing columns
        ElseIf CurrentColumns < PriorColumns Then
        
            ColsToRemove = PriorColumns - CurrentColumns
            RemoveWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
            
            table2.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, RemoveWhereTable2 - table2Col) _
                .Resize(table2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, ColsToRemove) _
                .Columns.Delete
        
        End If
        
        ' update globals
        PriorCount = CurrentCount
        PriorRows = CurrentRows
        PriorColumns = CurrentColumns
        
        ' turn events back on
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    ' we're editing existing rows ; not adding or removing of rows
    Else

' escape hatch for adding to bottom or right
Escape:

        ' pause the application events, because other wise,
        ' they will trigger an infinite loop.
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        ' actually update the sheet that triggered Worksheet_Change
        '
        ' this macro is for sheet1, so apply the change without offset there.
        Sheets(1).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
        ' sync the updates to the table in the other sheet, being sure
        ' to offset the update since the other table might be in a
        ' different spot
        '
        ' this macro is for sheet1, so apply the change to Table2
        Sheets(2).Range(Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Address).Value = Target.Value
        
        ' start the application events again.
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    End If
    
End If

BailOut:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
OhNo:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume BailOut

End Sub
```

For syncing from `Table2` in `Sheet2` to `Table1` in `Sheet1`:

```vbs
Public PriorCount As Long
Public PriorRows As Long
Public PriorColumns As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    PriorCount = Application.Range("Table2").ListObject.Range.Cells.Count
    PriorRows = Application.Range("Table2").ListObject.ListRows.Count
    PriorColumns = Application.Range("Table2").ListObject.ListColumns.Count
End Sub

'
' When I wrote this code, only God and I understood it.
'
' Now, only God knows.
'
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'
' TODO: Handle column/row deletions that alter where the Table's absolute position is (low priority)
'
' if something goes wrong, let the user know
' and give up, being sure to re-activate events
On Error GoTo OhNo

' get references to both table objects
Dim table1 As ListObject
Set table1 = Application.Range("Table1").ListObject
Dim table2 As ListObject
Set table2 = Application.Range("Table2").ListObject

' get current count of cells and rows/cols
Dim CurrentCount As Long
Let CurrentCount = table2.Range.Cells.Count
Dim CurrentRows As Long
Let CurrentRows = table2.ListRows.Count
Dim CurrentColumns As Long
Let CurrentColumns = table2.ListColumns.Count

' if our current row or column counts differ from prior,
' *and* there is no intersection between the target and
' table, then it means that we've removed rows or columns
' on the edge.
If Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), table2.Range) Is Nothing _
    And ((CurrentRows <> PriorRows) Or (CurrentColumns <> PriorColumns)) Then

    ' Debug.Print "Edge removal"

    ' Turn off events to avoid infinite loop
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' calculate the offset between Table1 and Table2
    table1Row = table1.Range.Row
    table1Col = table1.Range.Column
    table2Row = table2.Range.Row
    table2Col = table2.Range.Column
    
    ' these directions must be switched between
    ' Sheet1 and Sheet2. the row and col offset
    ' tell us which direction to move to apply
    ' the change in the other sheet. here, we go
    ' from Table1 to Table2, so we subtract 1 from 2
    rowOffset = table1Row - table2Row
    colOffset = table1Col - table2Col

    ' this is actually a pretty straightforward thing to sync.
    ' get the edge of the rows or cols, and delete everything
    ' past that in the other table.

    ' removing rows
    If CurrentRows < PriorRows Then
    
        RowsToRemove = PriorRows - CurrentRows
        RemoveWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
        
        table1.DataBodyRange.Offset(RemoveWhereTable1 - table1Row - 1, 0) _
            .Resize(RowsToRemove, table1.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count) _
            .Rows.Delete
    
    End If
    
    ' removing columns
    If CurrentColumns < PriorColumns Then
    
        ColsToRemove = PriorColumns - CurrentColumns
        RemoveWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
        
        table1.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, RemoveWhereTable1 - table1Col) _
            .Resize(table1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, ColsToRemove) _
            .Columns.Delete
    
    End If
    
    ' turn events back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

' if the change occurred anywhere inside Table1, then sync it to
' Table2 as well
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), table2.Range) Is Nothing Then

    ' calculate the offset between Table1 and Table2
    table1Row = table1.Range.Row
    table1Col = table1.Range.Column
    table2Row = table2.Range.Row
    table2Col = table2.Range.Column
    
    ' these directions must be switched between
    ' Sheet1 and Sheet2. the row and col offset
    ' tell us which direction to move to apply
    ' the change in the other sheet. here, we go
    ' from Table1 to Table2, so we subtract 1 from 2
    rowOffset = table1Row - table2Row
    colOffset = table1Col - table2Col

    ' we're adding rows or columns
    If CurrentCount > PriorCount Then
    
        ' Debug.Print "Added"
        ' The only way for a target to be non-empty
        ' and for CurrentCount > PriorCount is for
        ' the user to be adding an entry to the
        ' bottom of the list or the right. let's
        ' check for that.
        
        ' let's assume target is totally empty
        targetEmpty = True
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            ' for adding rows, everything is empty.
            ' but for columns, the first row isn't empty.
            ' it's a default column header string.
            If cell.Value <> Empty And Not cell.Value Like "Column*" Then
                targetEmpty = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        
        ' if not... go to Escape. We're adding to the bottom or right.
        If targetEmpty = False Then GoTo Escape
        
        ' otherwise... handle injecting rows or columns.
        ' Disable events to perform updates on table2.
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        ' figure out what we're adding and where
        
        ' adding rows
        If CurrentRows > PriorRows Then
        
            ' for adding/removing rows/cols, they've
            ' already been added to Table1. Just need
            ' to update Table2
            RowsToAdd = CurrentRows - PriorRows
            AddWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
            
            For i = 1 To RowsToAdd
                table1.ListRows.Add (AddWhereTable1 - table1Row + i - 1)
            Next
        
        ' adding columns
        ElseIf CurrentColumns > PriorColumns Then
        
            ' for adding/removing rows/cols, they've
            ' already been added to Table1. Just need
            ' to update Table2
            ColsToAdd = CurrentColumns - PriorColumns
            AddWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
            
            For i = 1 To ColsToAdd
                table1.ListColumns.Add (AddWhereTable1 - table1Col + i)
            Next
        
        End If
        
        ' update globals
        PriorCount = CurrentCount
        PriorRows = CurrentRows
        PriorColumns = CurrentColumns
        
        ' turn events back on
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    ' we're removing rows or columns
    ElseIf CurrentCount < PriorCount Then
        Debug.Print "Deleted"
        
        ' turn off events to apply updates
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        ' removing rows
        If CurrentRows < PriorRows Then
        
            ' for adding/removing rows/cols, they've
            ' already been added to Table1. Just need
            ' to update Table2
            RowsToRemove = PriorRows - CurrentRows
            RemoveWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
            
            table1.DataBodyRange.Offset(RemoveWhereTable1 - table1Row - 1, 0) _
                .Resize(RowsToRemove, table1.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count) _
                .Rows.Delete
        
        ' removing columns
        ElseIf CurrentColumns < PriorColumns Then
        
            ColsToRemove = PriorColumns - CurrentColumns
            RemoveWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
            
            table1.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, RemoveWhereTable1 - table1Col) _
                .Resize(table1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, ColsToRemove) _
                .Columns.Delete
        
        End If
        
        ' update globals
        PriorCount = CurrentCount
        PriorRows = CurrentRows
        PriorColumns = CurrentColumns
        
        ' turn events back on
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    ' we're editing existing rows ; not adding or removing of rows
    Else

' escape hatch for adding to bottom or right
Escape:

        ' pause the application events, because other wise,
        ' they will trigger an infinite loop.
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        ' actually update the sheet that triggered Worksheet_Change
        '
        ' this macro is for sheet2, so apply the change without offset there.
        Sheets(2).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
        ' sync the updates to the table in the other sheet, being sure
        ' to offset the update since the other table might be in a
        ' different spot
        '
        ' this macro is for sheet2, so apply the change to Table2
        Sheets(1).Range(Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Address).Value = Target.Value
        
        ' start the application events again.
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
    End If
    
End If

BailOut:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
OhNo:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume BailOut

End Sub
```

The diff, showing what references changed where:

```
6,8c6,8
<     PriorCount = Application.Range("Table1").ListObject.Range.Cells.Count
<     PriorRows = Application.Range("Table1").ListObject.ListRows.Count
<     PriorColumns = Application.Range("Table1").ListObject.ListColumns.Count
---
>     PriorCount = Application.Range("Table2").ListObject.Range.Cells.Count
>     PriorRows = Application.Range("Table2").ListObject.ListRows.Count
>     PriorColumns = Application.Range("Table2").ListObject.ListColumns.Count
32c32
< Let CurrentCount = table1.Range.Cells.Count
---
> Let CurrentCount = table2.Range.Cells.Count
34c34
< Let CurrentRows = table1.ListRows.Count
---
> Let CurrentRows = table2.ListRows.Count
36c36
< Let CurrentColumns = table1.ListColumns.Count
---
> Let CurrentColumns = table2.ListColumns.Count
42c42
< If Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), table1.Range) Is Nothing _
---
> If Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), table2.Range) Is Nothing _
61,62c61,62
<     rowOffset = table2Row - table1Row
<     colOffset = table2Col - table1Col
---
>     rowOffset = table1Row - table2Row
>     colOffset = table1Col - table2Col
72c72
<         RemoveWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
---
>         RemoveWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
74,75c74,75
<         table2.DataBodyRange.Offset(RemoveWhereTable2 - table2Row - 1, 0) _
<             .Resize(RowsToRemove, table2.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count) _
---
>         table1.DataBodyRange.Offset(RemoveWhereTable1 - table1Row - 1, 0) _
>             .Resize(RowsToRemove, table1.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count) _
84c84
<         RemoveWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
---
>         RemoveWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
86,87c86,87
<         table2.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, RemoveWhereTable2 - table2Col) _
<             .Resize(table2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, ColsToRemove) _
---
>         table1.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, RemoveWhereTable1 - table1Col) _
>             .Resize(table1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, ColsToRemove) _
99c99
< If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), table1.Range) Is Nothing Then
---
> If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), table2.Range) Is Nothing Then
112,113c112,113
<     rowOffset = table2Row - table1Row
<     colOffset = table2Col - table1Col
---
>     rowOffset = table1Row - table2Row
>     colOffset = table1Col - table2Col
153c153
<             AddWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
---
>             AddWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
156c156
<                 table2.ListRows.Add (AddWhereTable2 - table2Row + i - 1)
---
>                 table1.ListRows.Add (AddWhereTable1 - table1Row + i - 1)
166c166
<             AddWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
---
>             AddWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
169c169
<                 table2.ListColumns.Add (AddWhereTable2 - table2Col + i)
---
>                 table1.ListColumns.Add (AddWhereTable1 - table1Col + i)
196c196
<             RemoveWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
---
>             RemoveWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Row
198,199c198,199
<             table2.DataBodyRange.Offset(RemoveWhereTable2 - table2Row - 1, 0) _
<                 .Resize(RowsToRemove, table2.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count) _
---
>             table1.DataBodyRange.Offset(RemoveWhereTable1 - table1Row - 1, 0) _
>                 .Resize(RowsToRemove, table1.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count) _
206c206
<             RemoveWhereTable2 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
---
>             RemoveWhereTable1 = Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Column
208,209c208,209
<             table2.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, RemoveWhereTable2 - table2Col) _
<                 .Resize(table2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, ColsToRemove) _
---
>             table1.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, RemoveWhereTable1 - table1Col) _
>                 .Resize(table1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, ColsToRemove) _
234,235c234,235
<         ' this macro is for sheet1, so apply the change without offset there.
<         Sheets(1).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
---
>         ' this macro is for sheet2, so apply the change without offset there.
>         Sheets(2).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
240,241c240,241
<         ' this macro is for sheet1, so apply the change to Table2
<         Sheets(2).Range(Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Address).Value = Target.Value
---
>         ' this macro is for sheet2, so apply the change to Table2
>         Sheets(1).Range(Target.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Address).Value = Target.Value
```